# SMS-приложение на Android

Tags: android, sms

Вопрос в следующем.
Сильно начинающий программист.
Т.е. вообще никак пока.

Однако, есть идея написать приложение.
Есть web-сайт оператора. На котором есть отдельная страничка, отправляющее "сколькохочешь" бесплатных СМС-сообщений.
Решил трансформировать эту web страничку в небольшое приложение.
Выбор "кода" из 7 имеющихся, графа с самим номером, бокс для текста, ниже считанная с сайта капча (тоже не  представляю, как это сделать), бокс для ввода капчи.
Кнопка "Отправить"

Жду разных советов, что и где почитать, где посмотреть примеры и так далее.
Спасибо :)

Comment: > Сильно начинающий программист. Т.е. вообще никак пока.

Может лучше будет для начала определится с языком, на каком вы программировать собрались, выучить его, написать пару-тройку программок, для повышения своего чсв как программиста, убедится, что с точки зрения архитектуры они никакие, переписать их по 10 раз, постепенно усложняя, а только потом браться за "SMS-приложение на Android"?

Comment: Согласен. Просто услышал мнение, что конвертация статичной web страницы в приложение - далеко не ад. И для начала потестить неплохо.
Опять же - что посоветуете?

Answer (score 1):

Все, что вы хотите сделать - достаточно просто. Дело стоит за малым. Нужно всего-то ничего - научиться программировать.

1. Проанализировать, как отправляется запос из браузера.
2. Скачать HTML код страницы.
3. Достать оттуда ссылку на изображение с капчей
4. вывести картинку капчи в ImageView.
5. Создать остальные поля для ввода
6. отправить запрос таким же образом, как из браузера

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего кинуть на страницу WebView и направлять его по данному адресу.
Получится мини-браузер, в котором будет открываться этот сайт, и с ним можно будет работать, как из обычного браузера.

Чтобы придумать что-то более дельное, нужно потратить довольно много времени.
А его у всех в обрез.
Я бы Вам советовал сходить-таки на фриланс, заказать похожее приложение за деньги и по его образцу написать своё.